# Some basic questions about Django, Pyjamas and Clean URLs

Tags: django, web-applications, rest, clean-urls, pyjamas

I am farily new to the topic, but I am trying to combine both Django and Pyjamas. What would be the smart way to combine the two? I am not asking about communication, but rather about the logical part.

Should I just put all the Pyjamas generated JS in the base of the domain, say http://www.mysite.com/something and setup Django on a subdirectory, or even subdomain, so all the JSON calls will go for http://something.mysite.com/something ?

As far as I understand now in such combination theres not much point to create views in Django?

Is there some solution for clean urls in Pyjamas, or that should be solved on some other level? How? Is it a standard way to pass some arguments as GET parameteres in a clean url while calling a Pyjamas generated JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the good [Django With Pyjamas](https://github.com/pyjs/pyjs/wiki/pyjamaswithdjangojsonrpc) Howto.

Comment: Bang! This website doesn't exist anymore. Please update your answer.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to get the following to work, but it's not ideal.  Full disclosure:  I haven't figured out how to use the django's template system to get stuff into the pyjamas UI elements, and I have not confirmed that this setup works with django's authentication system.  The only thing I've confirmed is that this gets the pyjamas-generated page to show up.  Here's what I did.

- Put the main .html file generated by pyjamas in django's "templates" directory and serve it from your project the way you'd serve any other template.
- Put everything else in django's "static" files directory.
- Make the following changes to the main .html file generated by pyjamas:  in the head section find the meta element with name="pygwt:module" and change the content="..." attribute to content="/static/..." where "/static/" is the static page URL path you've configured in django;  in the body section find the script element with src="bootstrap.js" and replace the attribute with src="/static/bootstrap.js".

You need to make these edits manually each time you regenerate the files with pyjamas.  There appears to be no way to tell pyjamas to use a specific URL prefix when generating together its output.  Oh well, pyjamas' coolness makes up for a lot.

Answer (score 1):

acid, I'm not sure this is as much an answer as you would hope but I've been looking for the same answers as you have.

As far as I can see the most practical way to do it is with an Apache server serving Pyjamas output and Django being used as simply a service API for JSONrpc calls and such.

On a side note I am starting to wonder if Django is even the best option for this considering using it simply for this feature is not utilizing most of it's functionality.

The issue so far as I have found with using Django to serve Pyjamas output as Django Views/Templates is that Pyjamas loads as such

Main html page loads "bootstrap.js" and depending on the browser used bootstrap.js will load the appropriate app page.  Even if you appropriately setup the static file links using the Django templating language to reference and load "bootstrap.js", I can't seem to do the same for bootstrap.js referencing each individual app page.

This leaves me sad since I do so love the "cruftless URLS" feature of Django.

Comment: Just a sidenote, I moved away to Ruby and Rails long time ago. :-)